# Scala idiom for partial models?

Tags: scala

I am writing a HTTP REST API and I want strongly typed model classes in Scala e.g. if I have a car model `Car`, I want to create the following RESTful `/car` API:

1) For `POST`s (create a new car):

```
case class Car(manufacturer: String, 
               name: String, 
               year: Int)
```

2) For `PUT`s (edit existing car) and `GET`s, I want tag along an `id` too:

```
case class Car(id: Long, 
               manufacturer: String, 
               name: String, 
               year: Int)
```

3) For `PATCH`es (partial edit existing car), I want this partial object:

```
case class Car(id: Long, 
               manufacturer: Option[String],
               name: Option[String], 
               year: Option[Int])
```

But keeping 3 models for essentially the same thing is redundant and error prone (e.g. if I edit one model, I have to remember to edit the other models).

Is there a typesafe way to maintain all 3 models? I am okay with answers that use macros too.

I did manage to combine the first two ones as following

```
trait Id {
  val id: Long
}

type PersistedCar = Car with Id
```

Comment: Just commenting on what feels like a code/design smell. Your actual entity is the car - with id, and that's what your domain model should contain, and that's what should be persisted. Your REST requests CRU[D] model transient operations - create car, update car, get car, and you should have an object model that makes it clear they're requests.

Comment: @Paul: Even if I create separate models for all these and say I have a domain model `Car.scala` and an object model `CreateCarRequest.scala`, a lot of the fields are repeated over and over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I managed to solve this using a little library that I wrote:
https://github.com/pathikrit/metarest

Using above library, this simply becomes:

```
import com.github.pathikrit.MetaRest._

@MetaRest case class Car(
  @get @put id: Long, 
  @get @post @put @patch manufacturer: String, 
  @get @post @put @patch name: String, 
  @get @post @put @patch year: Int)
)
```

Answer (score 5):

I would go with something like that

```
  trait Update[T] {
    def patch(obj: T): T
  }

  case class Car(manufacturer: String, name: String, year: Int)

  case class CarUpdate(manufacturer: Option[String], 
                       name: Option[String], 
                       year: Option[Int]) extends Update[Car] {
    override def patch(car: Car): Car = Car(
      manufacturer.getOrElse(car.manufacturer),
      name.getOrElse(car.name),
      year.getOrElse(car.year)
    )
  }


  sealed trait Request
  case class Post[T](obj: T) extends Request
  case class Put[T](id: Long, obj: T) extends Request
  case class Patch[T, U <: Update[T]](patch: U) extends Request
```

With Post & Put everything is straightforward. With Patch a bit more complicated. I'm pretty sure CarUpdate class can be replaced with auto generated with macros.

If you'll update you Car model, you'll definitely will not forget about patch, because it will fail at compile time. However this two models looks too "copy-paste-like".

Answer (score 3):

You could represent your models as [Shapeless records](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#extensible-records), then the `id` is simply one more field on the front, and the mapping to/from options can be done generically using ordinary Shapeless type-level programming techniques. It should also be possible to generically serialize/deserialize such things to JSON (I have done this in the past, but the relevant code belongs to a previous employer). But you would definitely be pushing the boundaries and doing complex type-level programming; I don't think mature library solutions with this approach exist yet.

Comment: Good idea. Is there a JSON serialization for shapeless records?

Comment: I've seen people talking on IRC about implementing such a thing, but I'm not aware of any complete, published solutions. (Like I said, I once wrote one myself but it belongs to my previous employer)

Comment: https://github.com/fommil/spray-json-shapeless contains almost (but not quite) all of the code that would be needed to implement this.

Answer (score -1):

While I do agree with Paul's comment (yes, you'd have a lot of duplicated fields, but that's because you are decoupling the external representation of the fields to the internal representation of the fields, which is a good thing in case you want to change your internal representation without changing the API), a possible way to achieve what you want could be (which, if I understood correctly, is to have a single representation):

```
case class CarAllRepresentationsInOne(
   id: Option[Long] = None, 
   manufacturer: Option[String] = None, 
   name: Option[String] = None, 
   year: Option[Int] = None)
```

Since you have default values for everything set to None, you can instantiate this CClass from all the routes with the only disadvantages being of having to use named parameters during instantiation and checking for None in all the usages of the fields.

But I would strongly recommend having different types for your internal representation and for each possible external request resource: it may seem like duplication of code at the beginning, but the way you model cars inside your world should be separated by the resources used by the external world, in order to decouple them and allow you to change internal representation without changing the api contract with the outside when new needs arise.

Comment: Yes, this would work. I was looking for something more strongly typed e.g. I don't want to manually check in my `PUT` request that all these are `isDefined` and I don't have to check that in my POST the `id` is `None`. The amount of assertions I would end up writing to check validity would probably amount to the same number of lines of code if I had used explicit models in the first place. Also, I can easily make a mistake. Adding a new field to my `Car` model now necessitates adding its assertions too. Why should I write dynamic checks when the compiler can do static checks for me!

Comment: Agreed. But the reason from which these issues stem, imho, is a bad decision: you should have an internal car representation (with optional id) and 3 different resources objects, one for each route, with the precise fields. In this way you can also delegate validation to the outside objects (with 'requires' maybe) and assume that w/e is internal is OK. (That's my usual workflow in general)

Comment: May I ask the down-voters why they feel that the answer required down-voting? I'm open to learning, but you need comments! >.<